# wxPython - GetValue() and panels

Tags: python, wxpython

I've done some tests, and, dunno why, **GetValue()** prints what I type if the parent is set to **self**, the frame, but not if it's set to **self.panel**.I need the **TextCtrl** to be in the panel. Where's the mistake, and how to make it work properly?

```
import wx
class APP(wx.Frame):
    def __init__(self,parent,id,title):
        wx.Frame.__init__(self,parent,id,title)
        self.panel=wx.Panel(self)
        self.INPUT = wx.TextCtrl(self,-1,value="")  ############ Here
        self.Bind(wx.EVT_TEXT_ENTER, self.ONPRESSENTER, self.INPUT)

    def ONPRESSENTER(self,event):
        print self.INPUT.GetValue()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = wx.App()
    frame = APP(None,-1,'TextCtrl in a panel - GetValue Test')
    frame.Show(True)
    app.MainLoop()
```

It will work this way,and we're out of the panel, but simply change wx.TextCtrl(**self**,-1,value="") into **self.panel**, and it won't print the string we type in.

Forgive me if it's something stupid, im a noob :D

Python 2.7

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The TextCtrl should have the wx.Panel as the parent. You should always have a panel as the first and only child widget in a frame as it adds tabbing support and makes the app look correct on all platforms. If you want to catch every text event, you want wx.EVT_TEXT, not wx.EVT_TEXT_ENTER. See the edited example below:

```
import wx

class APP(wx.Frame):
    def __init__(self,parent,id,title):
        wx.Frame.__init__(self,parent,id,title)
        self.panel=wx.Panel(self)
        self.INPUT = wx.TextCtrl(self.panel,-1,value="")  ############ Here
        self.Bind(wx.EVT_TEXT, self.ONPRESSENTER, self.INPUT)

    def ONPRESSENTER(self,event):
        print self.INPUT.GetValue()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = wx.App()
    frame = APP(None,-1,'TextCtrl in a panel - GetValue Test')
    frame.Show(True)
    app.MainLoop()
```

Comment: Awesome, thank you. One more thing. I used the print cmd to test this thing out, but in my program, it has to be Return, and I wanted to trigger 'ONPRESSENTER' when the users press Enter, it doesn't have to return it for every character submitted. It would be useless and maybe it will cause some issues. Any tip to set it like I said? Thank you again for your help!

Comment: You'll probably want to bind to EVT_KEY_DOWN and then check if the key pressed was WXK_RETURN.  See http://wxpython-users.1045709.n5.nabble.com/wxPython-Capturing-the-ENTER-key-event-in-a-wxTextCtrl-td2275914.html for more.